# How many ways to arrange energy packets shown in system A and B?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability

[image: This is the question]

I tried very hard to solve this. I have attached the solution which I tried. Help me out to find the exact way to solve this

[image: Solution which I tried]

Comment: http://umdberg.pbworks.com/w/page/104869513/Example%3A%20Arranging%20energy%20and%20entropy have a read of this, it is related and might help. Or at least list where you  looked, that way someone might give you a hint, as you know homework type questions are not for here, but the internet has plenty of similar questions to yours. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Muhammad, FWIW, I highly recommend "Introduction to Thermal Physics" by Schroeder, it's a  very good book imo, covering  both thermodynamics and statistical mechanics. Also, your handwriting is much better than mine :) see if it suits you on Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct. The entropy is $kLn(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is the number of accessible states. You need to know $\omega$.
For the second case just proceed with your equation and you will get 144. Therefore the entropy is greater in the second case. The equilibrium is where the entropy is greatest.